# Validate email address using function and call it in the main

Tags: c, validation

I'm trying to write a function that check e-mail...using simple tests.
I wrote this code but I don't know what's wrong with it.
All that I need in the validation:

- One or more characters, followed by '@', followed by one or more characters, followed by '.', followed by one more more characters.
- Must not contain spaces.
- Must be unique!

Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int valid_mail(char x[]);
int main()
{
     do{
char mail[100];
gets(mail);
}while(valid_mail(mail)==-1);
  return 0;
}

int valid_mail(char x[])
    {
   int count=0;
int countp=0;
int i,j;
int t,t2;
int k=0;
for(i=0 ; i<strlen(x) ; i++)
{
    if(x[i]=='@')
    {
        count++;
        t=i;
    }
}
if(count==1)
{
    for(j=0; j<t ; j++)
    {
        if(!(x[j]=='_' || x[j]=='.' || isalpha(x[j]) || isdigit(x[j])))
        {
            k=-1;
            printf("\nInvalid e-mail\n");
            break;
        }
    }
    if(k==0)
    {
        for(i=0; i>t ; i++)
        {
            if(x[i]=='.')
            {
                t2=i;
                countp++;
            }
        }
        if(countp==1)
        {
            for(i=0; i<t2 && i>t2; i++)
            {
                if(!(isalpha(x[i])))
                {
                    k=-1;
                    printf("\nInvalid e-mail\n");
                    break;
                }
                else
                {
                    k=1;
                }
            }
            if(k==1)
            {
                if(x[t2+3]!='\0')
                {
                    k=-1;
                    printf("\nInvalid e-mail\n");
                }

            }
        }
        else
        {
            k=-1;
            printf("\nInvalid e-mail\n");
        }
    }
}
else
{
    k=-1;
    printf("\nInvalid e-mail\n");
}
return k;

}
```

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it belongs on the Code Review stackexchange

Comment: so I didn't understand what do you mean

Comment: It would be better suited to http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: What is the problem? You are using `gets()` which is a bad idea (use `fgets()` instead, but remember to remove the newline).  Your main loop structure is incorrect; you don't validate that you got input.  You'd have less repetition if you simply had `valid_email()` return the OK/not OK status and the calling code decided what to print (which should include the invalid email address). The code should also report when the address is OK.  You don't have any storage for previous emails, so you can't enforce the uniqueness constraint.  The testing code is rococo.  You could use `isalnum()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your variable naming scheme makes your code hard to read. Using `i` and `j` as loop variables is idiomatic and fine, but `x` as the string, `t` as a temp-index into the string... There's not reason for one-char variable names if you use a more modern editor than Notepad.

You also might break the code up into smaller functions, which makes testing and comprehension much easier:

```
// takes an email address and returns the domain portion (if the local portion
// validated) or NULL if the local portion did not validate.
char* validate_local_address(char* email) {
    for (char* ptr = email; *ptr; ptr++) {
        if (*ptr == '@' && ptr != email) {
            // check that we saw at least one character
            return ptr+1;
        } else if (*current == ' ') {
            return 0;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: thank you for your  notes but this code is a part of a project where i used alot of variables .